# How to set NullValueHandling.Include JsonSerializerSettings in a NEST client via ModifyJsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, jsonserializer

In a c# application I'm doing

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.ModifyJsonSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings() 
    { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include });
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

However it does not have any effect, null fields are not indexed in elasticsearch.

My goal is to set the serializer so that it will include all the null fields in the object. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To get null values to be stored/indexed in Elasticsearch you will need to modify your mappings to handle null values. According to the [Mapping Core Types documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html)

> When there is a (JSON) null value for the field, use the null_value as the field value. Defaults to not adding the field at all.

Which means if there is a null value for a field in the document you are indexing, unless the `null_value` is set in the mapping for that field, elasticsearch will not add that field to the document. An example of how to set an indexed field to accept null values would be like this example from the above documentation link. See the `message` field...

```
 {
     "tweet" : {
         "properties" : {
            "user" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "null_value" : "na"},
            "postDate" : {"type" : "date"},
            "priority" : {"type" : "integer"},
            "rank" : {"type" : "float"}
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem.  
According to [Core Types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html)  

**If the message has a null value, then the value that will be stored is na.**
  
The Json serialized does not send the value at all if a value is null and the serializer is set to .Ignore  
Adding the attribute 

`[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]`

solves the problem, but I'm using a generated DataContext object and it will be re-generated in the future.

Comment: Elasticsearch.org link has died.  Use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html instead.